# iPhone - Making a Tab Bar Transparent

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit

How do I make a tab bar transparent in cocoa touch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `UITabBar` is a subclass of `UIView`, have you tried adjusting its `alpha` property?

Note that if you are trying to modify a tab bar associated with a `UITabBarController`, you should consider this warning from Apple, located in [the reference for `UITabBar`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> **Important:** In iOS 3.0 and later, you
>   should not attempt to use the methods
>   and properties of this class to modify
>   the tab bar when it is associated with
>   a tab bar controller object. Modifying
>   the tab bar in this way results in the
>   throwing of an exception. Instead, any
>   modifications to the tab bar or its
>   items should occur through the tab bar
>   controller interface. You may still
>   directly modify a tab bar object that
>   is not associated with a tab bar
>   controller.

Comment: Thanks, alpha was just what I needed.  For anyone else who needs to try this. lets say your tabbar is called tabBar just go:    tabBar.alpha = 0.5  // sets transparency to 50%

Answer (score 3):

Now with iOS 5 you can change the UITabBar appearance to make only the background transparent with a simple line of code:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.2]];
```

Comment: And where would this go? I tried it in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` but it had no effect.