# Regarding Tab Bar

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitabbar

How can i make a UITabBar transparent. Is it possible?
If yes please help.
Thanx for your co-operation.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735076/iphone-making-a-tab-bar-transparent

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here is answer ...

```
@interface UITabBarController (private)
- (UITabBar *)tabBar;
@end

@implementation CustomUITabBarController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 48);
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [v setBackgroundColor:kMainColor];
    [v setAlpha:0.5];
    [[self tabBar] addSubview:v];
    [v release];

}
@end
```

Yes it is possible !