# iOS transparent uitabbar not working

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, uitabbar

I'm trying to have transparent tabbar in my application so the user can see the `uitableview` behind the tabBar.

I've seen all the topics here and haven't succeded yet.

I have the following code in my AppDelegate:

```
UITabBar *tabBar = [self.tabBarController tabBar];

if ([tabBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:)])
{
    tabBar.opaque = NO;
    tabBar.alpha = 0.8;
    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.9]];
    [tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent-tabbar.png"]];    
}
```

I just don't succeded with disabling the default black background of the tab bar.

What am I missing?

By the way the file transparent-tabbar.png is:
http://www.fastup.co.il/images/49382332.png

Thanks.

Comment: please see these two links, hope it will help.

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735076/iphone-making-a-tab-bar-transparent>

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800474/custom-uitabbar-background-image-not-working-in-ios-5-and-later>

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is not that you cant set the image, or that you cant get rid of the black color, the problem is in `UITabBarController` the viewcontrollers you add does not reach behind the `UITabBar`

So the problem that occurred that there is a black view bellow the `UITabBar`, so even if you remove the tabBar what you will see is a black view (try to set `tabBar.hidden = YES;`)

A workaround is to set the superView of `tabBar` to a color

```
tabBar.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

This would fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try the change the background image of the tabbar items not tabbar black ground..May be it will help.I have not implemented it yet..